# Conditional Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a Makefile with changeable sources and compiler.

Basically, what I want it to do is display a message in green if the compilation worked out well and in red otherwise. Additionally I want to avoid displaying the usual error messages (and compilation messages) a Makefile produces. (As I tried to do with all the '@')

Here's what I have for now :

```
COMP    = gcc

NAME    = test

RM      = rm -f

SRC     = main.c

OBJS    = $(SRC:.c=.o)

CFLAGS  = -Werror

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME):
        @$(COMP) -c $(SRC)
        @$(COMP) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

ifeq ($?, 0)
        @echo -e '\033[1;32;40mCompilation : OK\033[0m'
else
        @echo -e '\033[1;31;40mCompilation : ERROR\033[0m'
endif

clean:
        @$(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    @$(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

All it does is display "Compilation : ERROR" when it compiles well, but I thought that if `$?` equals 0 that meant it worked out, so I can't find any explanation.

Would you know how to make it do what I'm looking for?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : Wonderful help from many of you, I'm still looking into the recipe but I've found a way to simply display when it succeeded and when it failed.

```
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
        @$(COMP) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) && echo -e "\033[32mCompilation: OK\033[0m" || echo -e "\033[31mCompilation: ERROR\033[0m"
```

I'll keep on digging, thanks.

Comment: You're trying to mix bash and make.   In your example the ifeq statement is resolved at the time the makefile is read (not after the previous recipe was run), so $? is meaningless.   You should likely do this from a concatenated recipe.

Comment: It is normally a very bad idea to remove the error out from the output of make. There are a lot of editors which parse the compiler output to track them for later user guidance. vim capture this output and you can step from error to error in the editor. Removing this feature makes the build process a black hole!

Comment: How interesting haha, thanks for the input, I believe I have found a way to display the error message without touching those errors.

Comment: That edited command will hide the error from make and make will not exit with a failure when it should. In this case that doesn't really matter since your `$(NAME)` target is your final target but if it wasn't then a later target which depended on that target would fail because the file was missing when it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 2):

`$?` is a shell variable not a make variable, you are testing a make variable with that `if` statement and the recipe for your target only ever has the one `echo` line in it.

(See the output from `make -qp` to see what I mean.)

To do what you want you would need a **shell** test on `$?` however realize that make will exit on the first failing command so you will *never* see the failure echo output this way (unless you capture/hide the failure from make with an `if` or similar construct on the compilation command).

Something like this will work for capturing/hiding the exit status from the compilation from make but allow you to use it.

```
@if $(COMP) -c $(SRC); then \
    echo -e '\033[1;32;40mCompilation : OK\033[0m'; \
else \
    _ret=$$?; \
    echo -e '\033[1;31;40mCompilation : ERROR\033[0m'; \
    exit $$_ret;\
fi
```

The bit with `_ret` is to have make exit with the exit code of the compilation and not a static `exit 1` or whatever.

Comment: I see, so as you said, there is no direct way to display an error with a personal message. But I'm intrigued, can't I simply display a red "Compilation : ERROR" before exiting? You've talked of capturing / hiding the failure, could you give me some precision on this? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You absolutely can display any failure message you want you just need to make sure make doesn't see the failure before you do.

Comment: Understood, but may I ask how? I'll look into it.

Comment: Wonderful, but aren't those shell commands? I though only "ifeq" could be applied to Makefiles and not "if".

Comment: A makefile recipe line can include any bash command, including concatenated commands and commands that contain if statements.

Comment: Oh I see ! I'm looking a bit more into it but it seems very practical for this situation. Thanks a lot for your answers you two.

Comment: The $ need to be doubled up on `$?` and `$_ret` -- Aruixe -- a quick explanation -- if make sees `$X`, it will assume that `X` is a make variable, and try to expand `$X` (it will likely expand to blank).   If make sees `$$X`, it will expand `$$` to `$`, and pass that to the shell, giving the shell `$X`, which the shell will expand when it runs.   I made the same mistake in my post (though I've corrected it now).

Comment: @John Indeed. Copy/paste error without thinking. I've just edited to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like this:

```
$(NAME):
    @$(COMP) -c $(SRC)
    @$(COMP) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS); \
    if [ $$? == 0 ]; then \
        echo -e '\033[1;32;40mCompilation : OK\033[0m'; \
     else \
        echo -e '\033[1;31;40mCompilation : ERROR\033[0m'; \
     fi; \
     true
```

Notice that I used the '\' to concatinate the bash command with the if statement, so they all appear as a single recipe.   I also added a true statement to the end such that no matter what the if statement returns, the concatenated recipe will return true, and make will not fail.   You could also do:

```
  $(NAME):
       @$(COMP) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)  || echo ....
```

where the echo would only print if the previous command failed.

Comment: Interesting, being new to all of this this helps out a lot, and thanks for the precise explanation. I've tried it out by replacing my current $(NAME) with the first one you've proposed but it does not seem to fit. The '@' and the 'if' don't seem to be recognized. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: oops, yes the `@` is a makefile thing, and can't be put in the recipe.   I'll edit the answer...

Comment: So where should that piece of script go? Not directly in the Makefile? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: Are you asking about the `@`?    Basically, a makefile recipe is split into 'lines'.   A line contains an optional prefix (like `@`) and a complete bash command.   In this case the bash command is actually three bash commands on several lines, concatenated by \ s.    Because bash itself does not understand `@`, you cannot have an `@` in the middle of the bash command.   The `@` at the beginning of the recipe line will effect the whole recipe line.

Comment: `fi \ true` will not work correctly (syntax error, you need a semi-colon) also returning `true` on compilation failure is wrong and will cause things to break at a later (somewhat unrelated) place in the process.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.  Also added the missing $ in front of $$?... I should likely test these things before I post :-).   I returned true because the OP mentioned they would like to avoid the makefile error output, etc, so I was assuming they wanted the build to succeed regardless of whether this particular recipe succeeded, and that they just wanted an error print on failure.

Comment: They did seem to indicate that they might want that but that's a bad idea in make contexts in general (and this is a poorly written makefile already) so I didn't think it a good idea to add to the poor practice.